# C# IHttpHandler and the use of httpclient for a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

I have been tasked with maintaining an C# web service that pretty much boils down to the following code that is used in conjunction with IIS 8:

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    {
    // here we process the request and return it after fetching some data
    }
}
```

Now I need to create another web service, which in turn will request another web service for fetching data. What I've gathered is that the HttpClient() in C# is the new shiny, however finding out how to implement it in my case is not so easy (or if that would be a good solution).

My solution would something like

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    {
    // make sure that the incoming request is valid
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // do stuff with ^client and request the other service
    [..]
    // return the data from the response from ^client to the first request
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track or would this be a catastrophe? I would gladly take tips or pointers to relevant documentation.

Comment: I would reuse HttpClient, reinstantiating it on every call is very inefficient.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest It's not inefficient, but it can *potentially* kill your server if it's used heavily.

Comment: Would making it static and placing it outside ProcessRequest method be better?

Comment: @Steve if you use async you should not have this problem

Comment: @Steve Not at all, `HttpClient` is [fully re-entrant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

Comment: @FailedUnitTest Yea you guys are right. I got mixed up with WebClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach.

First, as others have said, HttpClient must not be created for each request, as this would result in your server creating one new TCP connection for each request **and** not dispose it from your connection pool until they reach their MaxIdleTimeout.

This is because each instance of HttpClient (or rather, each instance of HttpClientHandler) creates a unique ConnectionGroup within the ConnectionPool, so two HttpClient (created in such a way) will not share the same connections.

You can quite easily exhaust your ports (because connections are kept alive for quite some time), and even without that, you'll have all the performance issues you might find when deactivating keepalive (typically when connecting on a HTTPs server).

As for a solution, you might add a private readonly HttpClient field in your handler that you would initialize as you've done in your code (I believe HttpHandlers are instanciated once by IIS, not per-request, as long as it says it's reusable). (Edit: note that HttpClient instances are thread-safe).

The other problem you'll find is that IHttpHandler are synchronous by design. This means you'll have to return task.Result in your code. This will block the current thread (let's call it A), and all subsequent processing of the outbound request (sending the body of the request, reading the header of the response and reading the body of the response) will spawn use a thread from the thread pool to process this (let's call them B, C, and D, though they can all be the same thread since no step overlap in time).

But in Asp.net, you cannot safely do that. When your main thread A is processing an Asp.net inbound request, it will, simply put, lock the current context. And when threads B, C and D will be spawn to process the outbound request, they too, will try to acquire and lock the current context. But because your main thread A is blocked, the context has not been released. This will effectively result in deadlocks (A locks the context and wait for B/C/D, B/C/D wait for the context).

To work around this, I would advise you to use instead a **IHttpAsyncHandler**. Async process are not made to be used synchronous, and HttpClient can only be used in an async way.

However, this might prove much more challenging for a first usage scenario. It would be much more easier to use a HttpClient from the context of a WebApi server. However, without any knowledge as to why you have to use a HttpHandler, I do not know if this would be in the realm of acceptable answers.

There are other way to run asynchronous tasks and wait synchronously for them (such as changing temporary the CurrentContext), but they're all very dangerous.

As a side note, HttpClient is the new shiny thing, and works quite well with other new shiny things such as "all-the-way async infrastructure". But trying to use it HttpClient in an older infrastructure is not as easy.

Comment: The use of HttpHandler is just legacy. When looking into what we should use instead, there seem to be alot of documetenation on flashy restful api and such, which is not what we need I think. But the takeaway from your post is that using httpclient that way that I thought is not optimal.

Comment: And just to clarify - I think our process is synchronous since we have to wait for the response for the second request to complete to be able to response to the initial request to our handler. For that i think WebRequest Class might be of a better use for us? Or am I thinking about this totaly wrong?

Comment: In the context of .net, synchronous means that the thread that starts the operation is fully dedicated to it until it completes. So, when some IO happen like reading a filesystem or sending an HTTP request, the dedicated thread wait for them to complete, entering a suspended state. Asynchronous, on the other hand, means that the thread that started the operation is released at the first IO. When the IO completes, a callback is sent to resume the operation on another thread.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the synchronousness of an http call. You could have your inbound request arrive, be handled by a thread in an asynchronous handler. When sending the outbound query, the handling thread would be released. At that point, your response is not sent yet, so the consumer app still wait for a response from your inbound request to come, but internally, there is no thread blocked so from the point of view of the server this is asynchronous. When your outbound response is triggered, a callback is executed, and it feeds the inbound socket with a response. So it can be async.

Comment: Now, if you still prefer to stick with a synchronous model, directly using a WebRequest is much safer. It's outdated, but so is synchronous model after all

Comment: Oh, thank you for that explanation. It seems like async model might be the way to got. Will read up on all this some more.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution example:

```
public class YourApp
{
    private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Requests about to start!");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var result = Client.GetAsync("http://www.stackoverflow.com").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Requests are finished!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was somewhat similar to my prototype playing with httpclient, but I need to push the response from the httpclient get to the original request - the IHttpHandler. Should I rather have my httpclient code in a class that gets initiated everytime in ProcessRequest method?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but why not include "private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();" in the same class?

Comment: I think our process is synchronous since we have to wait for the response for the second request to complete to be able to response to the initial request to our handler. For that i think WebRequest Class might be of a better use for us instead of httpclient? Or am I thinking about this totally wrong?